# Testing signifiance of random effects on large dataset

Tags: r, mixed-model, model-selection

I want to do a mixed linear model, with two hierarchical random effects. I want to determine wether if these random effects are worth including in the model.

I have tried so far doing :

```
library(nlme)

# Mode lwith random effects but no fixed effects
lme1 <- lme(var ~ 1, random=~1|r.var1/r.var2,
                 correlation = corCompSymm(form=~1|var1/var2),data)

# Model without random effects
gls.data <- gls( var ~ 1, data)


# Compare the two
anova(lme1 , gls.data)
```

Which gives :

```
    call    Model df    AIC     BIC       logLik    Test    L.Ratio p-value
lme1        1     5    -3776601 -3776542  1888305           
gls.data    2     2    -3718476 -3718452  1859240  1 vs 2   58130   <.0001
```

The problem is : I have a very large dataset (>1 million observations). Statistical tests tend to always give significative results on big datasets. My question is : do I include these random effects to my model or not ? (and also, am I doing the right test ? )

Thanks

P.S. : I am not really a statistician, so if the answer must contain a lot of matrices and statistical calculation, would it be possible to explain it in detail ?

Comment: Unless your research question is specifically a hypothesis on whether the hierarchical effects exist, I wouldn't bother with a formal hypothesis test. Use $\Delta \text{AIC}$, plus a descriptive plots (I advise `DHARMa` in R to check mixed models - it's basically an equivalent to normal QQ, residuals vs fitted, but for GLMMs), plus your expert knowledge of the subject to assess if you should include the random effects.

Comment: I have to verify if these random effects exist. I want to know whether if there is an individual effect (var2 with 160000 levels) or an environnement effect (var1 with 1500 levels) on a parameter. The problem is that there is no preexistant knowledge on these effects. I also have fixed effects to test.

Comment: There's varying levels of "verify if random effects exist". As you say in the question body, statistical tests tend to give significant results on big datasets. That's because these nearly everything has an effect, regardless of how small the effect is. That's what the significance testing finds. I don't know exactly what your field or research question requires, but often, finding support for random effects via AIC and model fit tests like DHARMa are good enough.

Comment: I generally start with a model with a full set of covariates though, plus random effects, and then whittle the model down from there. This approach is inspired by the "ten step process" from Zuur's "Mixed Effefts Models and Extensions in Ecology with R", except that I don't like using hypothesis testing for dropping terms - I prefer to use AIC

Comment: Okay thanks, I am not used to using AICs, I will look into it and into the method you use.